# JQuery accordion doesn't work without h3 tags

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am trying to make an accordion with JQuery and am running into some trouble. The JQuery website shows to create your accordion content like this.

```
<div id="accordion">
    <a href="#">First header</a>
    <div>First content</div>
    <a href="#">Second header</a>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

When I do this the accordion doesn't work right and something is wrong with the formatting. If I put h3 tags around the header anchors like so

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

It works. Does anyone know why this happens? It happens in Firefox 3.5 and IE 8. I also just downloaded the JQuery files today.

-Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You must initialize the accordion with the header option specified:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({ 
  header: 'a' 
});
```

You also might want to check out the [jQuery Accordion API](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion) for more options.

Answer (score 8):

You must set the appropiate [header option](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-header).

In your case you want to use the anchors as the headers:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
  header: "a"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
<script>

jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion({heightStyle: "content",header: 'h3' });

</script>
```

This will works fine in IE