# JQuery Accordion Auto Height issue

Tags: jquery, accordion

I am using JQuery Accordion. I have this page here: http://www.hauppauge.com/site/support/support_colossus.html#tabs-6

What happens is the Auto Height is taking some time to load, before it loads there is a lot of white space below the content. When it finally does load the height will expand to longer then snap up to the correct height of the content. Is there a way for this to be seamless? I just want to be able to click an Accordion tab and have it expand smoothly to the exact height of the content.

**Update 08/08/2014:**

Use `heightStyle: "content"` if you're using [version 1.9 and higher](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/accordion/#option-heightStyle) ([Tarun's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1896608/tarun-gupta) answer)

Use `autoHeight: false` for [1.8 and lower](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/accordion/#option-autoHeight) (iappwebdev's answer)

Comment: You are applying height to `274` somewhere. try to remove it or at least reduce it.

Comment: I just did a search for this and I have no idea where I have this. How do you see that? Thank You!

Comment: Inspect with Firebug. the default height is `274` it should not be that much

Answer (score 57, accepted):

So why don't you just set `autoheight` to false?

```
$( ".selector" ).accordion({ autoHeight: false });
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-autoHeight

**EDIT**

Looking at your comment:

```
// Accordion
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
$("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true });
$("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: false, navigation: true });
```

You are initialising the accordion and then you add more options to it. Why are you doing that? Default value for `autoHeight` is `true`, so every tab gets a fixed height. Put all options in one call:

```
// Accordion
$("#accordion").accordion({
    header: "h3",
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true 
});
```

**EDIT**

Regarding your 2nd comment:

Have a look at http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-header. You can see that option `h3` is set by default, so you don't have to set it in your call.

And you get an answer to your question here: [JQuery accordion doesn't work without h3 tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183751/jquery-accordion-doesnt-work-without-h3-tags).

It's pretty important to go through jQuery API to improve your knowledge. For jQuery API go to http://api.jquery.com/ and for jQuery UI go to http://jqueryui.com/demos/. If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask **after** you tried to resolve your problem and **after** you did some research.

If all this answered your question, please mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I did, this is what I have:
    // Accordion
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
    $("#accordion").accordion({ collapsible: true });
    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
    autoHeight: false,
    navigation: true });

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! As you can tell I am learning. I really appreciate you help with this! It was driving me crazy.
Would you happen to know why the header: "h3" is needed? It won't work properly without it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the API link, I will look through that. I'm familiar with the demo link, that is where I was getting a lot of the code from. I think what was confusing me is I also took code from this page [http://www.hauppauge.com/jquery/index.html][1]


  [1]: http://www.hauppauge.com/jquery/index.html
downloaded from JQuery and there they use the h3. I'm new to this but will definitely read through the API page. 

Thanks again!

Comment: The { autoHeight: false } option was not documented in the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/ Thanks!

Answer (score 170):

you should use

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 

heightStyle: "content" 

});
```

It will set height according to your content. and will not use blank space as height.

Comment: thumbs up. short simple and best of all, it works :)

Comment: Thank you, Have tried `autoHeight: false` ... but nothing, this did the trick

Comment: This is the best answer! Thumbs up - change the accepted answer TA!

Comment: So long as you are using jQuery UI 1.9 or later, this is the best answer, as the OP mentions in his edit.

Comment: Phew, saved lot of time. Thanks. Worked perfect.

Comment: @deadend where you have added element #accordion in html

Comment: Good to see it is still helpful even after 6 years, hit upvote who find it right in 2019

Answer (score 16):

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ 

heightStyle: "content" 

});
```

This is working in new version
its worked for me !!!

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works so far, just resize the jQuery Accordion `contentElement` - it is called `data-content` by default, unless you configured it differently:

```
$('.accordion').find('[data-content]').resize();
```

This would also work if you want to resize the Accordion after your data is loaded dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({ 
 autoHeight: false,
 collapsible: true,
 navigation: true 
 });
```