# Jquery-ui: Reloading and refreshing accordions in inactive tabs sets height of accordion panels

Tags: jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page with a set of tabs, two of which contain accordions. I have several AJAX functions that reload the content of both sets of accordions, and once complete, I refresh both of them.

While the accordion of the currently active tab refreshes just fine, the one in the inactive tab does not. It opens the top accordion panel, and its height is just fine. But when you activate any other panel, it only has the minimal height and adds a scroll bar.

How can I get the accordions in the inactive tabs to maintain the proper height?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Accordion Auto Height issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034756/jquery-accordion-auto-height-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i believe ur issue is similar to this thread, pls check out these links.                                   [JQuery Accordion Auto Height issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034756/jquery-accordion-auto-height-issue)                       http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the duplicate post. Like I said, the active tab's accordion was working fine. I thought it was an issue related to accordions inside inactive tabs.