# jQuery Accordion auto height issue: too much white space/height

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-accordion

I know this has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11034756/jquery-accordion-auto-height-issue), but I have tried everything in that thread and similar posts and cannot figure this out.

```
$(function() {
$("#notaccordion1").accordion({autoHeight: 'false', heightStyle: 'content', collapsible: true, active: false});
});
```

Each of my expandable accordion divs has a bunch of white space at the bottom. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/tH4rd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Accordian `CSS` has quite a bit of padding set around the div.  You can override this with your own css.

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tH4rd/1/

The same applies for the white space above if you want to get rid of that padding set the `padding-top: 0px` as well.

**Update**

Here is an update based off your second example.

Here you don't need the `css` because you are not using paragraphs in your accordion which add extra padding.  All I did was modify your `myAccordion` function so that it closes the rest of the open accordion sections when a new one is opened.  (It wasn't doing that before)

http://jsfiddle.net/tH4rd/3/

Comment: @miles Please mark this answer as accepted if it helped resolve you question.  Or give feedback if it did not.  Thanks

Comment: I added the CSS, but I'm still seeing the same issue http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/tH4rd/

Comment: @miles I'm not seeing your updated fiddle..  The one you posted is your original one.  Do you see the issue on the fiddle I posted in my answer?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue on your fiddle, here is the updated one with the persisting issue: http://jsfiddle.net/pfeff/tH4rd/2/

Comment: @miles well its not working because your calling `$("#notaccordion1").accordion();` instead of `$("#notaccordion1").myAccordion();`  `No matter what parameters I put with `.myAccordion()` it makes it so that the height of each accordion is set to the height of the accordion with the most text.  So every accordion gets the same height.  Your using `jquery ui `1.8` which is a bit outdated and I can't find much documentation on. If you are looking to implement the accordion so that when you click on a dropdown the previous one closes I can look into a solution for you using your myAccordion fn.

Comment: @miles I updated my answer.  Here is the new fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tH4rd/3/

Comment: @miles Please mark this answer as accepted it if answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by simply putting on my css file the following line

```js
.ui-accordion-content {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

It worked fine with me.

Answer (score -2):

Also your original code sets autoHeight: 'false', this setting only works for me without the quotes so may possibly have been the cause of all the space.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment and does not answer the OP's question.